# azure mobileservice proxy authentication required

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing a Windows Store app that stores data in Azure using Azure MobileServices.  Everything is working fine as long as I'm not using a proxy but as soon as the connection to my mobile service goes through a proxy, I get a HttpRequestException: *"The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."*

I am using an instance of *MobileServiceClient* class to connect to my mobile service.

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "https://xxxxxx.azure-mobile.net/",
        "xxxxxx"
    );
```

How can I make the Windows Store app use the default system proxy (like specified in LAN settings in IE) to connect to an Azure MobileService?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the problem of Azure or Mobile Services, this is entirely the problem of using Windows Store apps with web proxies requiring authentication.

Microsoft [acknowledges](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778122/en-us) this problem but does not provide any solution for now except for white-listing the address you want to access so that it bypass the proxy call.

Comment: Thanks, although not what I was hoping for. Hopefully Microsoft will come with a solution soon.